# How to resolve "list has no attribute find"

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import randint

alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
#print(alpha[25])

#defining key
key = randint(1,26)
print(key)

a = input('Pls enter your character : ')
#print(a)

#ecrypting character
p = aplha.find(a)
print(p)
```

Output:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b373cc86a531> in <module>()
     12 
     13 #ecrypting character
---> 14 p = aplha.find(a)
     15 print(p)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: `aplha` vs `alpha`. What is `aplha`?

Comment: That error doesn't seem to be possible if you change `aplha` to `alpha`. Make sure you didn't leave an old variable in scope if you're developing in an interactive shell.